# Como ler um arquivo com lua?

Tags: lua

Qual função utilizo para ler dados de um arquivo em `Lua`?

Por exemplo:

```
lua_folder/
.... config.json
.... main.lua
```

Quero abrir esse arquivo `config.json` através do `Lua`.

Answer (score 2):

Faz uma função para fazer isso assim:

```
 function file_getdata()
    local data_file_path = gre.SCRIPT_ROOT .. "/myfile.json"
    local f = io.open(data_file_path)
    f = io.read("*all")
    f = io.close()
    return f
 end
```

[Fonte do código](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-07/msg00457.html)